# Combining large number of files in one file using terminal

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, tail, gzip

I have 600 files that I want to combine/merge into one. I've done that using the following command on Mac terminal:

```
  cat neutral_*.msOut.gz > neutral.msOut
```

Each file has the following format:

```
 // Initial random seed:
 1824618124544

 // RunInitializeCallbacks():
 initializeMutationRate(0);
 initializeMutationType(1, 0.5, "f", 0);
 initializeGenomicElementType(1, m1, 1);
 initializeGenomicElement(g1, 0, 1099999);
 initializeRecombinationRate(1e-08);

 // Starting run at generation <start>:
 1 

 #WARNING (Subpopulation::ExecuteMethod_outputXSample): outputMSSample() should probably not be called from an early() event in a WF model; the output will reflect state at the beginning of the generation, not the end.
 #OUT: 1 SM p3 208

 //
 segs: 3
 positions: 0.0012,0.19383,0.18383
 001
 110
 111
```

When merging these files I only want to include the top 15 lines (that are the same in each file) once in the final merged file. How can this be achieved using Mac terminal?

Comment: Why do what appear to be unzipped text files have names like `*.gz`?  Are you showing the unzipped content of the files?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Note: I believe my answer is exactly what you needed. Please mark as Answer and / or up vote if this is true, otherwise please explain what exactly did you need.

Comment: IMHO, the command you cited in your question: `cat neutral_*.msOut.gz > neutral.msOut` produces a merged **binary compressed** output file: **neutral.msOut** - that should be probably called: **neutral.msOut.gz**. If you meant to produce a text file, it still needs to be decompressed. Therefore the commands you would need to  execute to just join all of the text content of those compressed files to a single text file ( without the exclusions of the first 15 lines, like in my answer ) would need to be: `cat neutral_*.msOut.gz > neutral.msOut.gz` and: `gunzip neutral.msOut.gz`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need first to unzip before to remove the 15 first lines

```
for i in neutral_*.msOut.gz
do
  zcat $i | head -15 $i > neutral.msOut
  break
done

for i in neutral_*.msOut.gz
do
  zcat $i | sed -e 1,15d >> neutral.msOut
done
```

- the first loop just extracts one time the first 15 lines in one file to have them one time in the result file, the loop can be simplified knowing the name of one of the files to just extract the first 15 lines of it. If you do not want to have that header in the produced file just remove that loop
- the second loop adds all except the first 15 lines of each files
- that does not require to have a given version of *tail* (see remark in deleted answer of @kabanus saying [tail does not have a `-q` option on osx](https://ss64.com/osx/tail.html) )
- may be you need to zip `neutral.msOut` after the two loops

Comment: FYI @Bruno: Simon Sheppard updated the: [https://ss64.com/osx/tail.html] today, since I mentioned it to him yesterday. However, since Simon was too busy to update the macOS version of the site, the rest of the macOS pages may not be up to date for a while. So in meantime, just try to use the Terminal `man` command to get the actual info for each supported command.

Answer (score 2):

Use sed:

```
sed -e '1,15d' neutral_*.msOut.gz > neutral.msOut
```

But from your comments, it seems that you also want to unzip the file.  If so:

```
for i in neutral_*.msOut.gz; do gzip -dc "$i" | sed -e 1,15d; done > neutral.msOut
```

Comment: But it only excludes top 15 lines from the first file it reads. Not the rest of the files.

Comment: No, this excludes the first 15 lines of each file. Perhaps your comment was meant for bruno's answer.

Comment: Ah...unless you have multiple files zipped in each .gz file and you are trying to work on all of them.  In that case, you'll have to unpack each gzip onto the file system.  Also, you'll need to modify your question to provide the actual details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: perhaps @Peter imagines the _sed_ is done _after_ the _for_ something like `(for i in neutral_*.msOut.gz; do gzip -dc "$i"; done) | sed -e 1,15d` but this is not the case here and in my answer even using several lines this is more visible in mine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

### From your question I understand, that:

1. You have 600 gzip compressed text files, with **neutral_*.msOut.gz** pattern, in your **MACOS** directory.
2. You want to produce a single uncompressed text file: **neutral.msOut**, that combines the text lines of all of the 600 files above, excluding the first 15 lines of each of these text files.

---

### If above is true, do the following 3 steps in your Mac's Terminal:

1. CD to the directory that you keep the 600 neutral_*.msOut.gz files in.
2. Execute: `gunzip neutral_*.msOut.gz` # to decompress the 600 files.
3. Execute: `tail -q -n '+16' neutral_*.msOut > neutral.msOut` # to create the result text file.

---

### The options used in tail explained:

1. `-q` - prevents each file fragment to be prepended with the file info
2. `-n '+16'` - select the tail portion starting at text line number 16

Comment: Dear @bruno, I had removed my comment regarding the 15 first lines, since the OP decided your solution is correct, and I do agree. However: My solution, while possibly less efficient (I did not test that) does exactly what it claims - merges lines: 16-EOF of each originally zipped file to a single text file. Also, your unsubstantiated `tail -q` tale is just that... a tall tale :) Just type `man tail` in macOS Terminal app, to see: `SYNOPSIS tail [-F | -f | -r] [-q] [-b number | -c number | -n number] [file ...]` &: `-q Suppresses printing of headers when multiple files are being examined.` :)